# Passing AJAX GET results to location

Tags: php, ajax, get, opencart, bitcoin

Here's my problem

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#button-confirm').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'index.php?route=payment/bitcoinpayflow/confirm',
        success: function(url) {
             location = '<?php echo $continue;?>';
        }       
    });
});
//--></script>
```

The url returns this:

```
https://bitcoinpayflow.com/ordersArray // note the lack of space between orders and array. Is this a problem? If it is, I can get it to display in JSON notation with some fiddling.
(
    [order] => Array
        (
        [bitcoin_address] => 1DJ9qiga2fe94FZPQZja75ywkdgNbTvGsW
    )

)
```

Now, what I want to do is append the entry bitcoin_address to $continue `'<?php echo $continue;?>'`. which stands for: `/index.php?route=checkout/success`. so it would read `/index.php?route=checkout/success&btc=1DJ9qiga2fe94FZPQZja75ywkdgNbTvGsW`. it seems like it should be simple but I can't see how to do it.

The next page has a javascript function that parses the bitcoin address from the url  and displays it on the page. This all works fine, I just can't get the bitcoin address to actually show!

Comment: And if you have any tips on how to better format this question, let me know. I am not used to the stackoverflow etiquette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it return JSON. You will reduce the amount of pain a lot. Apparently it's PHP, so just use PHP's json_encode(), then just use the JSON response to concatenate stuff to url in your 'success' function.

```
location = "<?php echo $location; ?>&btc=" + data.bitcoin;
```

...or something like that. Try console.log(data) if you're not sure what you're getting.

Comment: OK, it's now returning json.

particularly 
{
  "order" : { "bitcoin_address" : "1F2vgWSRcfRzZz1LetFxrk6qfWhpTeW32s"}
}

The + data.bitcoin. Is this saying "append the entry in the array that begins with order, then goes to bitcoin"

So for me it would be order.bitcoin_address ?

Thanks for your help, and welcome to stackoverflow (full of desperate humanities grads : ) )

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable in global scope and then access it within functions

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var btcaddress = null;

$('#button-confirm').bind('click', function() {
    if( isValidBtcAddress( btcaddress ) ){
      Url = 'index.php?route=payment/bitcoinpayflow/confirm' + btcaddress;
    }else{
      Url = 'index.php?route=payment/bitcoinpayflow/confirm';
    }

    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET',
        'url': Url,
        success: function(url) {
             location = '<?php echo $continue;?>';
        }       
    });
});



function someotherFunction( response ){
    btcaddress = response['order']['bitcoin_address'];
}
```